# Getting a wordlist from a DICT formatted dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I want a latin word list for research / reference purposes. (Like `/usr/share/dict/words`)

There would appear to be no such word list (`apt-file search /usr/share/dict | sort | uniq | grep latin`), but there is a DICT english latin dictionary: `dict-freedict-eng-lat`.

Is there an easy way to get a word list from this?

I tried some quick manual parsing of the `.dz` using `sed` but the format looks complicated enough that it needs a little parsing. I tried the `dictunformat` command, however it produces a *c5 database* which looks to be a binary format. I can't find tools to interact with such files.

Comment: Does it have to be a "DICT formatted dictionary"? You can get wordlists e.g. from spelling dictionaries (`ibritish`, `ibritish-huge`, ...) using e.g. aspell (`aspell -l en dump master | aspell -l en expand`).

Comment: That's useful to know and would apply in many cases. There doesn't seem to be a latin aspell dictionary in debian (`apt-cache search aspell  | grep latin`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `.dz` is a variant of gzip that allows to gunzip just the necessary chunks. 
Try:

```
zcat dict-freedict-eng-lat.dz
```

Most of the ".dz" are generated from more comprehensible formats (in the case 
the format is TEI) using freedict-tools.

**UPDATE:** (I like hacking solutions but) now the "not so hacking" way:

1) If you want Latin, get the sources of freedict Lat-Eng (the inverse dictionary):

```
wget "https://sourceforge.net/projects/freedict/files/Latin%20-%20English/0.1.1/freedict-lat-eng-0.1.1.src.tar.bz2"
```

2) unzip it:

```
tar -xvjf freedict-lat-eng-0.1.1.src.tar.bz2
```

and enjoy the pleasure of dealing with the sources...

3) get Latin entry (orth xml tag) from the XML-TEI source (lat-eng/lat-eng.tei):

```
xidel -e "//orth" lat-eng/lat-eng.tei
```

---

One last suggestion: use the Latin-German dictionary (more complete)

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/freedict/files/Latin%20-%20German/0.4/freedict-lat-deu-0.4.src.tar.bz2
tar ...
xidel -e //orth lat-deu/lat-deu.tei |  sort -u | wc        (9730)
```

Comment: Yep that's correct. It gives you something human readable. It's one of the first things I tried (together with a `head` and a `sed 0~2 p`) but there are multiline entries that confuse this (I think the index file might deal with these somehow)

Comment: @AttRigh, sorry I misunderstood the problem. I updated with a complementary suggestion.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't realise that freedict have a [nice collection of xml dictionaries](https://github.com/freedict/fd-dictionaries/search?utf8=✓&q=extension:tei&type=Code) in this xml [TEI format](http://www.tei-c.org/index.xml). These don't seem to be packaged by debian but can be fetched directly (as you do).

Comment: @AttRigh,  Installing one at the time is always a better Idea... (see also  `dict-freedict-all` -- it will show you the list of near 100 debian packages of freedicts)

Comment: Cool cool. I meant to say that the xml files aren't contained in the debian packages as far as I can tell.

Comment: Correct. I would like to see those XML-TEI files in some `/usr/share/dict....`

Comment: where does xidel come from?

Comment: @slashdottir, for example `http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html#downloads`

Answer (score 4):

```
zcat /usr/share/dictd/freedict-eng-lat.dict.dz | perl -e 'my %dict; $start=0; $/="\n"; while (<>) { next if $_ =~ m/(\/|\x90)/; chomp; $_ =~ s/[0-9\. ]*//g; $start = 1 if $_ eq 'abecedarium'; next if $start==0; @words=split(/\;/,$_); foreach my $word (@words) { $dict{$word}=1;} }; $,="\n"; print sort keys %dict;'
```

to uncompress file, skip all english lines containing */pronounciation/*, skip lines with weird DLE character, skip all header lines till we reach the first real word *"abecedarium"*, remove numbers, dots and spaces, split conjugations separated by *";"* and add every word to a hash to have unique entries.
in the end, print all words separated by $, set to new-line *\n*

sample output:

```
ager
agere
agna
agnellina
agnina
```

Comment: Thanks for doing the parsing I was too lazy to do :). I wonder if there's a more magic way with less code, but in the absence of other answers this works.

Comment: of course there is. `zcat /usr/share/dictd/freedict-eng-lat.dict.dz | grep -e '^ [a-zA-Z0-9]' | grep -o -P '[[:alpha:]]+' | sort -du`

Comment: it is just less efficient imho

Comment: cool +1 (just one warning: grep -o -P '[[:alpha:]]+' woud fail words like ævitas)

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an article on how to dump and convert Aspell dictionaries to wordlist and later to searchable MySQL/MariaDB database:

https://www.joe0.com/2018/02/13/how-to-dump-and-convert-aspell-dictionary-to-wordlist-or-searchable-mysql-mariadb-database/

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers on here.